# Chai js tests stop running when assert on 2 BigInts fails

Tags: solidity, chai, bigint, hardhat

I just had a strange case where my tests just stopped running when doing an `assert.equal` over 2 `BigInt`s without converting them to strings. And This only happens if the 2 `BigInt`s are not equal.

The following only works when both values in the `assert.equal` are equal otherwise all tests after it aren't run and I don't get the failed test log in the terminal

```
  describe("Test", () => {
    it("Test BigInt", async () => {
        const balanceBefore = BigInt(1)
        const proceeds = BigInt(0.5)

        const balanceAfter = BigInt(111.45)
        const gasCost = BigInt(0.05)

        assert.equal(
            balanceAfter + gasCost,
            balanceBefore + proceeds
        )
    })
```

**Does anyone have an explanation for why this is happening ?**

---

PS: for those actually looking for a solution, just do the `assert.equal` on `string`s not `BigInt`s.
Like this:

```
              assert.equal(
                  (balanceAfter + gasCost).toString(),
                  (balanceBefore + proceeds).toString()
              )
```